# Parse Login iOS – Does not log in user after signing up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, authentication

I am currently using Parse to create and log in users for my iOS app. After a user signs up with a new account, Parse does not log them in––it just clears the text fields. Some users get confused thinking the signup was unsuccessful, and try to put their information in again, prompting the "username taken" alert. How can I modify the Parse login so that it automatically logs in the user once they create a successful account? (I currently have a ParseLoginHelper class––would I make this modification in the PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate extension?)
If anyone has example code they would like to share in their answer, please note that I'm using Swift for my project.

Answer (score 1):

When you are signing up (register) a new users you don't need to call the logIn function again in order to log them in to the app. 
After the signing up process they are already logged in. In order to check if they are logged in you can check if the current user is not **nil**

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

}
```

At the end your sign up code should look like the following:

```
    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = "USERNAME"
    user.password = "PASSWORD"
    user.email = "EMAIL"
    // add more fields

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if succeeded {
            // here the current user should not be nil. 
            // if it is then please check for sessionToken
            if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
                // user is logged in
            }
        }

    }
```